# does python freeze the list before for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Say I have a list `l` and a thread **t1** iterating over `l` for ever:

```
while True:
    for i in l:
        #do something
```

and another thread **t2** randomly modify or delete members in `l`.

What happens after a deletion? Does **t1** detect that in the current loop?

**UPDATE**:

1. By freeze I mean **t1** get a copy of `l`. **t2** can modify `l` for
   sure
2. citing documentation or simple but persuading code snippet are
   welcomed.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Race condition bugs are notoriously hard to find. Therefore, trying it can only show that there is an obvious error, and cannot possibly show otherwise. Even worse, cpython's GIL will hide errors consistently.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I come up with this in my current project but this does not trigger a fatal error and I cannot find a simple but persuading example to reveal the truth.

Comment: @phihag: the GIL will hide errors in certain situations, to be sure, but this is a case that can very easily be checked by just sleeping while checking values across threads. It's a very simple question in that way and not one that the GIL *can* cause to "misbehave". And so it is that I state that the OP has not demonstrated any research effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The list is not frozen - your iterator will not "break" in the sense of raising an exception. Instead, it will keep moving forward through the list, with results that are possibly surprising.

Consider this code (Snippet at ideone here: http://ideone.com/0iMao):

```
l = list(range(10))
for i in l:
    print i
    try:
        del l[i]
    except (RuntimeError,IndexError), e:
        print e

print l
```

It produces this output:

```
0
2
4
5
7
list assignment index out of range
9
list assignment index out of range
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Which is probably not what you wanted or expected, although it is apparently well-defined: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement .

Instead, you can either lock the list, or take a copy. Note that `iter(l)` does not take a copy internally, and will have the same effect as just iterating over the list directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sort of thing you can observe:

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> from time import sleep
>>> liszt = ['first item', 'second item', 'third item', 'fourth item',
...         'plentee more items', "but I'm lazy"]
>>> def thread_one():
...     for i in liszt:
...             print 'Thread one found "%s"' % i
...             sleep(1)
... 
>>> def thread_two():
...     sleep(0.5)
...     print 'Thread two deleting first item.'
...     del liszt[0]
...     sleep(1)
...     print 'Thread two deleting fourth item.'
...     del liszt[3]
... 
>>> Thread(target=thread_one).start(); Thread(target=thread_two).start()
Thread one found "first item"
Thread two deleting first item.
Thread one found "third item"
Thread two deleting fourth item.
Thread one found "fourth item"
Thread one found "but I'm lazy"
```

From this you can see that modifying the list in one thread affected the iterator in the other thread; deleting the first item made the iterator skip an item, deleting a future item means it won't be seen in the iterator, because it's gone.

Here is a model of some of how this works; I'm not providing code for this explicitly, but you can work this out from observation.

```
State:             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Iterator position:  ^
```

Go to next item.

```
State:             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Iterator position:     ^
```

Delete first item.

```
State:             [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Iterator position:     ^
```

Go to next item.

```
State:             [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Iterator position:        ^
```

Delete fifth item.

```
State:             [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Iterator position:        ^
```

Et cetera. On the matter of threading, it doesn't matter whether you are doing it in one thread or multiple threads. Sure, you may have a race condition on whether the item is deleted or not, but it still works in the same way.

If you're not familiar with the internals of iteration, meet [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter). `for x in y` is iterating over `iter(y)`, in actual fact. So, you can play with the `iter(liszt)` listiterator object if you want, using `next()` on it while you fiddle with the list it's iterating over. More convenient than a for-loop in the interactive Python console.

Answer (score 0):

the list is accessible from both threads and not frozen.
the iterator will "know" that members have been removed and skip them, unless you have explicit index access beyond the length of the list.
the deletions themselves are thread safe.

if you want real locking of the list, protect it with a mutex or copy it.